# Game freezing while using pygame after pausing

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a chess engine with a reset function. I also have a feature where the screen doesn't allow the user to make any more moves after checkmate or stalemate.

However, if i execute my reset function after this, my game stays frozen.

I have two files in my code, my engine and my main. I'm quite sure this is something to do with my main file, however I have put in the engine just in case.

Here they are:

Main (ChessMate.py):

```
import pygame as p
import ChessEngine

WIDTH = HEIGHT = 512
DIMENSION = 8
SQ_SIZE = HEIGHT//DIMENSION
MAX_FPS = 15
IMAGES = {}


def loadImages():
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wK',
              'wQ', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bK', 'bQ']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = p.transform.scale(
            p.image.load('Chess/Images/' + piece + '.png'), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def main():
    p.init()
    screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(p.Color("white"))
    gs = ChessEngine.GameState()
    validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
    moveMade = False
    animate = False
    loadImages()
    running = True
    sqSelected = ()
    playerClicks = []
    gameOver = False
    while running:
        for e in p.event.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif e.type == p.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if not gameOver:
                    location = p.mouse.get_pos()
                    col = location[0]//SQ_SIZE
                    row = location[1]//SQ_SIZE
                    if sqSelected == (row, col):
                        sqSelected = ()
                        playerClicks = []
                    else:
                        sqSelected = (row, col)
                        playerClicks.append(sqSelected)
                    if len(playerClicks) == 2:
                        move = ChessEngine.Move(
                            playerClicks[0], playerClicks[1], gs.board)
                        print(move.getChessNotation())
                        for i in range(len(validMoves)):
                            if move == validMoves[i]:
                                gs.makeMove(validMoves[i])
                                moveMade = True
                                animate = True
                                sqSelected = ()
                                playerClicks = []
                        if not moveMade:
                            playerClicks = [sqSelected]
            elif e.type == p.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == p.K_z:
                    gs.undoMove()
                    moveMade = True
                    animate = False
                if e.key == p.K_r:
                    gs = ChessEngine.GameState()
                    validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
                    sqSelected = ()
                    playerClicks = []
                    moveMade = False
                    animate = False
                    checkMate = False
                    staleMate = False

        if moveMade:
            if animate:
                animateMove(gs.moveLog[-1], screen, gs.board, clock)
            validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
            moveMade = False
            animate = False

        drawGameState(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected)

        if gs.checkMate:
            gameOver = True
            if gs.whitetoMove:
                drawText(screen, ' Black wins by Checkmate')
            else:
                drawText(screen, ' White wins by Checkmate')
        elif gs.staleMate:
            gameOver = True
            drawText(screen, 'Stalemate')

        clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
        p.display.flip()


def highlightSquares(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected):
    if sqSelected != ():
        r, c = sqSelected
        if gs.board[r][c][0] == ('w' if gs.whitetoMove else 'b'):
            s = p.Surface((SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
            s.set_alpha(100)
            s.fill(p.Color('blue'))
            screen.blit(s, (c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE))
            s.fill(p.Color('yellow'))
            for move in validMoves:
                if move.startRow == r and move.startCol == c:
                    screen.blit(s, (SQ_SIZE*move.endCol, SQ_SIZE*move.endRow))


def drawGameState(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected):
    drawBoard(screen)
    highlightSquares(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected)
    drawPieces(screen, gs.board)


def drawBoard(screen):
    global colors
    colors = [p.Color("white"), p.Color("gray")]
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            color = colors[((r+c) % 2)]
            p.draw.rect(screen, color, p.Rect(
                c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def drawPieces(screen, board):
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            piece = board[r][c]
            if piece != "--":
                screen.blit(IMAGES[piece], p.Rect(
                    c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def animateMove(move, screen, board, clock):
    global colors
    dR = move.endRow - move.startRow
    dC = move.endCol - move.startCol
    framesPerSquare = 10
    frameCount = (abs(dR) + abs(dC)) * framesPerSquare
    for frame in range(frameCount + 1):
        p.event.pump()
        r, c = (move.startRow + dR * frame / frameCount,
                move.startCol + dC*frame / frameCount)
        drawBoard(screen)
        drawPieces(screen, board)
        color = colors[(move.endRow + move.endCol) % 2]
        endSquare = p.Rect(move.endCol*SQ_SIZE,
                           move.endRow*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE)
        p.draw.rect(screen, color, endSquare)
        if move.pieceCaptured != '--':
            screen.blit(IMAGES[move.pieceCaptured], endSquare)
        screen.blit(IMAGES[move.pieceMoved], p.Rect(
            c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
        p.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


def drawText(screen, text):
    font = p.font.SysFont("Helvetica", 32, True, False)
    textObject = font.render(text, 0, p.Color('Gray'))
    textLocation = p.Rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT).move(
        WIDTH/2 - textObject.get_width()/2, HEIGHT/2 - textObject.get_height()/2)
    screen.blit(textObject, textLocation)
    textObject = font.render(text, 0,  p.Color("Black"))
    screen.blit(textObject, textLocation.move(2, 2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And my engine (ChessEngine.py):

```
class GameState():
    def __init__(self):
        # 8x8 2d board, each element has 2 characters.
        self.board = [
            ["bR", "bN", "bB", "bQ", "bK", "bB", "bN", "bR"],
            ["bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp"],
            ["wR", "wN", "wB", "wQ", "wK", "wB", "wN", "wR"]]
        self.moveFunctions = {'p': self.getPawnMoves,
                              'R': self.getRookMoves, 'N': self.getKnightMoves, 'B': self.getBishopMoves, 'Q': self.getQueenMoves, 'K': self.getKingMoves}

        self.whitetoMove = True
        self.moveLog = []
        self.whiteKingLocation = (7, 4)
        self.blackKingLocation = (0, 4)
        self.checkMate = False
        self.staleMate = False
        self.enpassantPossible = ()
        self.currentCastlingRight = CastleRights(True, True, True, True)
        self.castleRightsLog = [CastleRights(
            self.currentCastlingRight.wks, self.currentCastlingRight.wqs, self.currentCastlingRight.bks, self.currentCastlingRight.bqs)]

    def makeMove(self, move):
        self.board[move.startRow][move.startCol] = "--"
        self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol] = move.pieceMoved
        self.moveLog.append(move)
        self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove

        if move.pieceMoved == 'wK':
            self.whiteKingLocation = (move.endRow, move.endCol)
        elif move.pieceMoved == "bK":
            self.blackKingLocation = (move.endRow, move.endCol)

        if move.isPawnPromotion:
            self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol] = move.pieceMoved[0] + 'Q'

        if move.isEnpassantMove:
            self.board[move.startRow][move.endCol] = '--'

        if move.pieceMoved[1] == 'p' and abs(move.startRow - move.endRow) == 2:
            self.enpassantPossible = (
                (move.startRow + move.endRow)//2, move.startCol)
        else:
            self.enpassantPossible = ()

        if move.isCastleMove:
            if move.endCol - move.startCol == 2:
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol -
                                        1] = self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol+1]
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol+1] = '--'
            else:
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol +
                                        1] = self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol-2]
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol-2] = '--'

        self.updateCastleRights(move)
        self.castleRightsLog.append(CastleRights(
            self.currentCastlingRight.wks, self.currentCastlingRight.wqs, self.currentCastlingRight.bks, self.currentCastlingRight.bqs))

    def undoMove(self):
        if len(self.moveLog) != 0:
            move = self.moveLog.pop()
            self.board[move.startRow][move.startCol] = move.pieceMoved
            self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol] = move.pieceCaptured
            self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove

        if move.pieceMoved == 'wK':
            self.whiteKingLocation = (move.startRow, move.startCol)
        elif move.pieceMoved == "bK":
            self.blackKingLocation = (move.startRow, move.startCol)

        if move.isEnpassantMove:
            self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol] = '--'
            self.board[move.startRow][move.endCol] = move.pieceCaptured
            self.enpassantPossible = (move.endRow, move.endCol)

        if move.pieceMoved[1] == 'p' and abs(move.startRow - move.endRow) == 2:
            self.enpassantPossible = ()

        self.castleRightsLog.pop()
        newRights = self.castleRightsLog[-1]
        self.currentCastlingRight = CastleRights(
            newRights.wks, newRights.bks, newRights.wqs, newRights.bqs)

        if move.isCastleMove:
            if move.endCol - move.startCol == 2:
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol +
                                        1] = self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol-1]
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol-1] = '--'
            else:
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol -
                                        2] = self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol+1]
                self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol+1] = '--'

    def updateCastleRights(self, move):
        if move.pieceMoved == 'wK':
            self.currentCastlingRight.wks = False
            self.currentCastlingRight.wqs = False
        elif move.pieceMoved == 'bK':
            self.currentCastlingRight.bks = False
            self.currentCastlingRight.bqs = False
        elif move.pieceMoved == 'wR':
            if move.startRow == 7:
                if move.startCol == 0:
                    self.currentCastlingRight.wqs = False
                elif move.startCol == 7:
                    self.currentCastlingRight.wks = False
        elif move.pieceMoved == 'bR':
            if move.startRow == 0:
                if move.startCol == 0:
                    self.currentCastlingRight.bqs = False
                elif move.startCol == 7:
                    self.currentCastlingRight.bks = False

    def getValidMoves(self):
        tempEnpassantPossible = self.enpassantPossible
        tempCastleRights = CastleRights(self.currentCastlingRight.wks, self.currentCastlingRight.bks,
                                        self.currentCastlingRight.wqs, self.currentCastlingRight.bqs)
        moves = self.getAllPossibleMoves()
        if self.whitetoMove:
            self.getCastleMoves(
                self.whiteKingLocation[0], self.whiteKingLocation[1], moves)
        else:
            self.getCastleMoves(
                self.blackKingLocation[0], self.blackKingLocation[1], moves)
        for i in range(len(moves)-1, -1, -1):
            self.makeMove(moves[i])
            self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove
            if self.inCheck():
                moves.remove(moves[i])
            self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove
            self.undoMove()
        if len(moves) == 0:
            if self.inCheck():
                self.checkMate = True
            else:
                self.staleMate = True
        else:
            self.checkMate = False
            self.staleMate = False
        self.enpassantPossible = tempEnpassantPossible
        self.currentCastlingRight = tempCastleRights
        return moves

    def inCheck(self):
        if self.whitetoMove:
            return self.squareUnderAttack(self.whiteKingLocation[0], self.whiteKingLocation[1])
        else:
            return self.squareUnderAttack(self.blackKingLocation[0], self.blackKingLocation[1])

    def squareUnderAttack(self, r, c):
        self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove
        oppMoves = self.getAllPossibleMoves()
        self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove
        for move in oppMoves:
            if move.endRow == r and move.endCol == c:
                return True
        return False

    def getAllPossibleMoves(self):
        moves = []
        for r in range(len(self.board)):
            for c in range(len(self.board[r])):
                turn = self.board[r][c][0]
                if (turn == 'w' and self.whitetoMove) or (turn == 'b' and not self.whitetoMove):
                    piece = self.board[r][c][1]
                    self.moveFunctions[piece](r, c, moves)
        return moves

    def getPawnMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        if self.whitetoMove:
            if self.board[r-1][c] == "--":
                moves.append(Move((r, c), (r-1, c), self.board))
                if r == 6 and self.board[r-2][c] == "--":
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (r-2, c), self.board))
            if c - 1 >= 0:
                if self.board[r-1][c-1][0] == 'b':
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (r-1, c-1), self.board))
                elif (r - 1, c - 1) == self.enpassantPossible:
                    moves.append(
                        Move((r, c), (r-1, c-1), self.board, enpassantPossible=True))

            if c + 1 <= 7:
                if self.board[r-1][c+1][0] == 'b':
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (r-1, c+1), self.board))
                elif (r - 1, c + 1) == self.enpassantPossible:
                    moves.append(
                        Move((r, c), (r-1, c+1), self.board, enpassantPossible=True))

        else:
            if self.board[r+1][c] == "--":
                moves.append(Move((r, c), (r+1, c), self.board))
                if r == 1 and self.board[r+2][c] == '--':
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (r+2, c), self.board))

            if c-1 >= 0:
                if self.board[r+1][c-1][0] == 'w':
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (r+1, c-1), self.board))
                elif (r + 1, c - 1) == self.enpassantPossible:
                    moves.append(
                        Move((r, c), (r+1, c-1), self.board, enpassantPossible=True))

            if c+1 <= 7:
                if self.board[r+1][c+1][0] == 'w':
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (r+1, c+1), self.board))
                elif (r + 1, c + 1) == self.enpassantPossible:
                    moves.append(
                        Move((r, c), (r+1, c+1), self.board, enpassantPossible=True))

    def getRookMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        directions = ((-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1))
        enemyColor = "b" if self.whitetoMove else "w"
        for d in directions:
            for i in range(1, 8):
                endRow = r + d[0] * i
                endCol = c + d[1] * i
                if 0 <= endRow < 8 and 0 <= endCol < 8:
                    endPiece = self.board[endRow][endCol]
                    if endPiece == "--":
                        moves.append(
                            Move((r, c), (endRow, endCol), self.board))
                    elif endPiece[0] == enemyColor:
                        moves.append(
                            Move((r, c), (endRow, endCol), self.board))
                        break
                    else:
                        break
                else:
                    break

    def getKnightMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        knightMoves = ((-2, -1), (-2, 1), (-1, -2), (-1, 2),
                       (1, -2), (1, 2), (2, -1), (2, 1))
        allyColor = "w" if self.whitetoMove else "b"
        for m in knightMoves:
            endRow = r + m[0]
            endCol = c + m[1]
            if 0 <= endRow < 8 and 0 <= endCol < 8:
                endPiece = self.board[endRow][endCol]
                if endPiece[0] != allyColor:
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (endRow, endCol), self.board))

    def getBishopMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        directions = ((-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1))
        enemyColor = "b" if self.whitetoMove else "w"
        for d in directions:
            for i in range(1, 8):
                endRow = r + d[0] * i
                endCol = c + d[1] * i
                if 0 <= endRow < 8 and 0 <= endCol < 8:
                    endPiece = self.board[endRow][endCol]
                    if endPiece == "--":
                        moves.append(
                            Move((r, c), (endRow, endCol), self.board))
                    elif endPiece[0] == enemyColor:
                        moves.append(
                            Move((r, c), (endRow, endCol), self.board))
                        break
                    else:
                        break
                else:
                    break

    def getQueenMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        self.getRookMoves(r, c, moves)
        self.getBishopMoves(r, c, moves)

    def getKingMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        kingMoves = ((-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1),
                     (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1))
        allyColor = "w" if self.whitetoMove else "b"
        for i in range(8):
            endRow = r + kingMoves[i][0]
            endCol = c + kingMoves[i][1]
            if 0 <= endRow < 8 and 0 <= endCol < 8:
                endPiece = self.board[endRow][endCol]
                if endPiece[0] != allyColor:
                    moves.append(Move((r, c), (endRow, endCol), self.board))

    def getCastleMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        if self.squareUnderAttack(r, c):
            return
        if (self.whitetoMove and self.currentCastlingRight.wks) or (not self.whitetoMove and self.currentCastlingRight.bks):
            self.getKingsideCastleMoves(r, c, moves)
        if (self.whitetoMove and self.currentCastlingRight.wqs) or (not self.whitetoMove and self.currentCastlingRight.bqs):
            self.getQueensideCastleMoves(r, c, moves)

    def getKingsideCastleMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        if self.board[r][c+1] == '--' and self.board[r][c+2] == '--':
            if not self.squareUnderAttack(r, c+1) and not self.squareUnderAttack(r, c+2):
                moves.append(
                    Move((r, c), (r, c+2), self.board, isCastleMove=True))

    def getQueensideCastleMoves(self, r, c, moves):
        if self.board[r][c-1] == '--' and self.board[r][c-2] == '--' and self.board[r][c-3] == '--':
            if not self.squareUnderAttack(r, c-1) and not self.squareUnderAttack(r, c-2):
                moves.append(
                    Move((r, c), (r, c-2), self.board, isCastleMove=True))


class CastleRights():
    def __init__(self, wks, bks, wqs, bqs):
        self.wks = wks
        self.bks = bks
        self.wqs = wqs
        self.bqs = bqs


class Move():
    ranksToRows = {"1": 7, "2": 6, "3": 5,
                   "4": 4, "5": 3, "6": 2, "7": 1, "8": 0}
    rowsToRanks = {v: k for k, v in ranksToRows.items()}
    filesToCols = {"a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 2,
                   "d": 3, "e": 4, "f": 5, "g": 6, "h": 7}
    colsToFiles = {v: k for k, v in filesToCols.items()}

    def __init__(self, startSq, endSq, board, enpassantPossible=False, isCastleMove=False):
        self.startRow = startSq[0]
        self.startCol = startSq[1]
        self.endRow = endSq[0]
        self.endCol = endSq[1]
        self.pieceMoved = board[self.startRow][self.startCol]
        self.pieceCaptured = board[self.endRow][self.endCol]

        self.isPawnPromotion = (self.pieceMoved == 'wp' and self.endRow == 0) or (
            self.pieceMoved == 'bp' and self.endRow == 7)

        self.isEnpassantMove = enpassantPossible
        if self.isEnpassantMove:
            self.pieceCaptured = 'wp' if self.pieceMoved == 'bp' else 'bp'

        self.isCastleMove = isCastleMove

        self.moveID = self.startRow * 1000 + \
            self.startCol*100 + self.endRow*10 + self.endCol

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Move):
            return self.moveID == other.moveID
        return False

    def getChessNotation(self):
        return self.getRankFile(self.startRow, self.startCol) + self.getRankFile(self.endRow, self.endCol)

    def getRankFile(self, r, c):
        return self.colsToFiles[c] + self.rowsToRanks[r]
```

Please help, it would be good enough for me if someone could just identify where the problem might be, because I'm really stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once `gameOver` is set to `True`, there are no code paths by which it can become `False` ever again.

Probably you just need to add it to the <kbd>r</kbd> reset handler:

```
        elif e.type == p.KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == p.K_z:
                gs.undoMove()
                moveMade = True
                animate = False
            if e.key == p.K_r:
                gs = ChessEngine.GameState()
                validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
                sqSelected = ()
                playerClicks = []
                moveMade = False
                animate = False
                checkMate = False
                staleMate = False
                gameOver  = False    ### <<-- HERE
```